# Triple loop into tensor matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, loops, matrix, tensor

I am aware of similar questions, but couldn't find a useful one for my problem

Is there a way to speed up my code by transforming this triple loop into matrix/tensor operations?

```
% preallocate
X_tensor = zeros(N, N, N);

% loop
for i = 1: N
    for k = 1: N
        for j = 1:N
            X_tensor(i,k,j) = X(i,j) * B(i,k) * Btilde(k,j)  / B(i,j);
        end
    end
end
```

EDIT
I am sorry, I forgot one important information:
X, B and Btilde are all NxN matrices

Comment: The first index is the one that changes most rapidly. Therefore, you should switch the order of the loops (`i` should be the inner loop, and `j` the outer loop). You can probably also vectorize the operation, which might or might not improve the speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vectorize the operation by permuting the matrices and using element-wise multiplication/division.

`i`, `k`, and `j` are dimensions `[1,2,3]`. Looking at the first term in the equation, that means we want to take the `[1,2,3]` order of `X` (where the third dimension is a singleton) and rearrange it to `[1,3,2]`. This corresponds to an index of `[i,j,k]`. `B` in the second term is already in the required `[1,2,3]` order.

So the loops can be replaced by:

```matlab
X_tensor2 = permute(X,[1,3,2]) .* B .* permute(Btilde,[3,1,2]) ./ permute(B,[1,3,2])
```

Here's a test program to verify correctness:

```
N = 5;
P = primes(400);
X = reshape(P(1:25),N,N);
B = reshape(P(26:50),N,N);
Btilde = reshape(P(51:75),N,N);

% preallocate
X_tensor = zeros(N, N, N);
X_tensor2 = zeros(N, N, N);

% loop
for i = 1: N
    for k = 1: N
        for j = 1:N
            X_tensor(i,k,j) = X(i,j) * B(i,k) * Btilde(k,j)  / B(i,j);
        end
    end
end

X_tensor2 = permute(X,[1,3,2]) .* B .* permute(Btilde,[3,1,2]) ./ permute(B,[1,3,2]);

isequal(X_tensor, X_tensor2)
```

Comment: Great answer! Is it actually faster?

Comment: @AnderBiguri In Octave with N=100, it's about 13.0s vs. 0.005s. But I would expect the difference to be much less pronounced with MATLAB and JIT.

Comment: @AnderBiguri thank you! I am sorry I forgot the dimension of the right hand side, does that change the approach? You created NxN matrices so it shouldn't, right? Just to be sure

Comment: @jack I assumed that they were NxN matrices because that's how you were indexing them in your loops. You should be able to verify that both approaches produce the same output (within floating point rounding errors) with your data.

Comment: @beaker Sorry, one last follow up question: why isn't the Btilde's permuntation [2,3,1] intead of [3,1,2]? I see that the test code would give a different result, but I can't see how that relates to the intuition. thanks again!

Comment: @jack The reason that it's [3,1,2] is that we want to permute the 1st and 2nd dimension of `Btilde` to `k` and `j`, or the 2nd and 3rd dimensions of our result. So the singleton dimension 3 is moved to the `i` dimension, 1. I'll try to make a diagram when I get a chance, but think of it as taking the two-dimensional array from the front of the cube and moving it to the top.

Comment: @beaker oh I see, it's where you move the singleton to the index, not the order of the dimensions (which coincided for the first 2 elements). Thank you!